# Brownian motion and independent increment

Tags: random-variables, brownian-motion, independence

We know that the Brownian motion has independent increment. So if we have the following: $$E[tB_t-B_s|\mathcal F_s]$$ which are the problem that arise? can I say that $E[tB_t-B_s|\mathcal F_s]= E[tB_t-B_s]$ and what is the distribution of $tB_t-B_s$?

Comment: $tB_{t}-B_{s}$ has no independent increments anymore? What do You mean by that? Is it a processes indexed by $R_{+}^{2}$? Maybe You are asking about $X_{t}=tB_{t}$? Have You tried calculating covariance of two increments? If it will be different then $0$, then they can not be independent.

Comment: @StanTuwim if for example I have $E[tB_t-B_s|\mathcal F_s]$ can I say that it is $=E[tB_t-B_s] $? Instead, what can I say of the distribution of $tB_t-B_s$? maybe what give a problem in this case is more the distribution than independence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I say that $E[tB_t-B_s|\mathcal F_s]= E[tB_t-B_s]$?

No, it is not true. Let us transform left-hand side a bit:
$$\mathbb{E}[tB_{t}-B_{s}|\mathcal{F}_{s}]=\mathbb{E}[tB_{t}-(t-t+1)B_{s}|\mathcal{F}_{s}]$$
$$=t\cdot \mathbb{E}[B_{t}-B_{s}|\mathcal{F_{s}}]+\mathbb{E}[(t-1)B_{s}|\mathcal{F_{s}}]$$
$$=t\cdot \mathbb{E}[B_{t}-B_{s}]+(t-1)B_{s}.$$

Note that, $E[tB_t-B_s]$ from Your proposal is a constant and 
$$t\cdot \mathbb{E}[B_{t}-B_{s}]+(t-1)B_{s}$$
 is not - because of $(t-1)B_{s}$ part.

> what is the distribution of $\mathbb{E}[tB_t-B_s|\mathcal{F}_{s}]$?

We know that $B_{s}\sim \mathcal{N}(0,s)$ and hence:

$$t\cdot \mathbb{E}[B_{t}-B_{s}]+(t-1)B_{s} \sim \mathcal{N}(t\cdot \mathbb{E}[B_{t}-B_{s}], (t-1)^2\cdot s).$$

> what is the distribution of $tB_t-B_s$?

Simillary, we have:
$$tB_t-B_s=t(B_{t}-B_{s}) + (t-1)B_{s},$$
$$t(B_{t}-B_{s})\sim \mathcal{N}(0, t^{2}(t-s)),$$
$$(t-1)B_{s}\sim \mathcal{N}(0,(t-1)^{2}s),$$
and $$t(B_{t}-B_{s})\perp (t-1)B_{s}$$ so we can simply add up parameters.